# Modifying Fraction Class and Test Driver JAVA

Tags: java

My Professor has created code that needs to be modified. The only problem is I don't understand his style at all on top of being a fairly new programmer myself. The parameters for the assignment are as follows:
•   Modify setters so that they ignore inappropriate values (i.e., divide by zero)
•   Implement the equals() method inherited from the top-level Object class
•   Implement less than and greater than methods
•   Implement add, subtract, and multiply methods

•   Makes sure the equals method returns true for any two fractions that are arithmetically equal.
•   Make sure that the equals method does not alter the values of the fractions being compared.
•   The lessThan and greaterThan methods must each return a Boolean value, not a string.
•   The provided reduce method returns a new (reduced) fraction object as its function value

I am completely lost about this assignment as I don't have the slightest clue where to even begin. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!!!! I have the feeling that once I see it done, it will all make sense to me. I am just not used to this style of teaching at all.

```js
public class Fraction {
        private int numer;
     private int denom;
    
     public Fraction() { // no-arg constructor
         numer = 0;
         denom = 1;
 }
    
     public Fraction(int numer, int denom) {
                this.numer = numer;
         this.denom = denom;
        }
     public Fraction(Fraction frac) { // copy constructor
         numer = frac.getNumer();
         denom = frac.getDenom();
     }

      // getters and setters
     public int getNumer() {
         return numer;
     }
    
     public void setNumer(int x) {
         numer = x;
     }
    

        public int getDenom()  {
         return denom;
     }
    
     public void setDenom(int x) {
            denom = x;
     }
   
  // Special Methods
     public String toString() {
         return numer + "/" + denom;
     }

     // Other Methods
     public Fraction reduce() {
         Fraction temp = new Fraction();
        
         int GCD = gcd(numer, denom);
        
         temp.setNumer(numer / GCD);
         temp.setDenom(denom / GCD);
        
         return  temp;
     }
  
  // Private Methods
     private int gcd(int n1, int n2)
     {
         int M, N, R;
        
         if (n1 < n2)
         {
              N = n1;
              M = n2;
         }
         else
         {
              N = n2;
              M = n1;
         }
        
         R = M % N;
        
         while (R != 0)
         {
              M = N;
              N = R;
            
              R = M % N;
         }
        
         return N;
        
        }
 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // test constructors
         Fraction frac0 = new Fraction();
         System.out.println("TESTING NO-ARG CONSTRUCTOR");
  System.out.println("frac0: Result should be 0/1:");
         System.out.println("Numer = " + frac0.getNumer());
         System.out.println("Denom = " + frac0.getDenom());
        
         System.out.println("TESTING int/int CONSTRUCTOR");
         Fraction frac1 = new Fraction(2,4);
  System.out.println("frac1: Result should be 2/4:");
         System.out.println("Numer = " + frac1.getNumer());
         System.out.println("Denom = " + frac1.getDenom());
        
         System.out.println("TESTING Fraction CONSTRUCTOR");
         Fraction frac2 = new Fraction(frac1);
  System.out.println("frac2: Result should be 2/4:");
         System.out.println("Numer = " + frac2.getNumer());
         System.out.println("Denom = " + frac2.getDenom());

  System.out.println("TESTING COPY CONSTRUCTOR frac1  frac2");
         if (frac1.getNumer() == frac2.getNumer() &&
              frac1.getDenom() == frac2.getDenom() &&
                frac1 != frac2)
         {
              System.out.println("Copy constructor working");
         }
         else
              System.out.println("PROBLEM with copy constructor");

        
         // test equal method
         System.out.println("TESTING EQUALITY OF frac1 and frac2 -");
  System.out.println("SHOULD BE FOUND EQUAL:");
  if (frac1.equals(frac2))
         {
              System.out.println("frac1 and frac2 found equal");
         }
         else
         {
              System.out.println("frac1 and frac2 NOT equal");
         }

             // test reduce method
         System.out.println("TESTING reduce METHOD ON frac1");
  Fraction reduced_frac1 = frac1.reduce();
         System.out.println("Reduced frac1 = " + reduced_frac1);
        
         // test getters and setters
         frac2.setNumer(8);
         frac2.setDenom(12);
         System.out.println("Numer = " + frac2.getNumer());
         System.out.println("Denom = " + frac2.getDenom());
        
         // System.out.println("GCD of 2/4 = " + frac1.gcd(1,4));
       
     }

 //* TO BE COMPLETED *
}
```

Comment: FYI - code snippets are only able to be run with Javascript.  What you have there is Java.

Comment: So you want us to do your homework? And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with his teaching methods and with some further study I am sure you can figure it out. No one here is going to do it for you and I don't want to do your homework so I will ask the common question, what have you tried so far? I've given you one of the modified setters. Keep working, study your java better or you are going to have a hard time when it gets difficult.

```
//Here is where you start
public void setDenom(int x){

    if(x > 0){
       denom = x;
    }else{
       //throw an error
    }

}
```

Comment: Should have clarified! Not looking for someone to do my homework. its the premade test driver that is throwing me off. I added a bit of code similar to this but the output was still the same. Should I be changing the value stored in the denom variable to test the error if it is equal to zero? just a little overwhelmed.

Comment: The output should be the same, because he doesn't ever test for a zero denom as far as I could read, that means that x > 0 is always true, which is fine in this case. Due diligence suggests that you should add a test to have it reach that error point.

Comment: would a scanner be necessary in the main function for user input or is it not needed with the info included in the test driver

Comment: You can do it however you like, but considering you already have a functioning test method provided by your professor I would just add in a statement that tested your "DENOM IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO ZERO" check. In reality you don't NEED to test it and should probably soldier on. Have you made more progress in implementing the other methods?